# Store different java classes in one arraylist/variable

Tags: java

I will start this question with an example and then I will tell what I have in my mind.

```
public class testCommand extends commandBase implements commandTypeA{

    //this is from commandTypeA
    @Override
    public type executable() {
        //type is enum
        return type.EVERYONE;
    }

    //this is from commandBase 
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "test";
    }
}

public class testCommand2 extends commandBase implements commandTypeB{

    //this is from commandTypeB
    @Override
    public String description() {
        return "A testCommand";
    }

    //this is from commandBase 
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

In that example I don't want to have `description` in `commandTypeA` and `executable` in `commandTypeA`

I will create also many classes like `testCommand` and `testCommand2`. I will always extend `commandBase` and will implement `commandTypeA` or `commandTypeB`.

I want to store those classes into an ArrayList or just a variable (that could store both of the classes - with implemented `commandTypeA` or `commandTypeB` and all of their methods - including methods from the extended and implemented classes).
Example with ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<*datatype*> registeredCommands = new ArrayList<*datatype*>;
registeredCommands.add(new testCommand());
registeredCommands.add(new testCommand2());
```

Example with variable:

```
*datatype* currentCommand = new testCommand();
currentCommand = new new testCommand2();
```

Also I need to perform actions later in my code like

Example with ArrayList:

```
system.out.println((commandBase) registeredCommands.get(0).name());
system.out.println((commandTypeA) registeredCommands.get(0).executable());
system.out.println((commandTypeB) registeredCommands2.get(1).description());
```

Example with variable:

```
*datatype* currentCommand = new testCommand();
system.out.println((commandBase) currentCommand.name());
system.out.println((commandTypeA) currentCommand.executable());

currentCommand = new new testCommand2();
system.out.println((commandTypeB) currentCommand.description());
```

My questions are:

- Is there any type of datatype that i could use in my case?
- Can I do the same thing I have in mind in other (better) ways?

Comment: How does your code know whether it can call `executable` or `description`? The answer to this question should tell you how to structure the code. In general, mixing different types with different interfaces in the same collection doesn’t really make sense. There are certainly exceptions to this but in a good design they’re rare.

Comment: I think PECS is very relevant here. [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any type of datatype that i could use in my case?

That depends on the use-case but you can use `CommandBase`, `CommandTypeA` or `CommandTypeB` directly or as boundaries for wildcards (I changed the class names as per common convetions).

**Example with variable:**

```
CommandBase currentCommand = new testCommand();
currentCommand = new testCommand2();
```

This is basically "program to interface" (in this case abstract base class), i.e. use the common type. Ideally you'd introduce a `Command` interfact that the others extend and `CommandBase` implements in which case you'd use

```
Command currentCommand = new testCommand();
```

When it comes to calling, you'd need `instanceof` and with pattern matching (as of Java 14) you can do it like this:

```
if( currentCommand instanceof CommandTypeA typeA) {
   typeA.execute();
}
```

Without pattern matching it would be like this:

```
if( currentCommand instanceof CommandTypeA) {
   ((CommandTypeA)currentCommand ).execute();
}
```

**Example with `List` (also an interface):**

```
List<Command> registeredCommands = new ArrayList<>();
registeredCommands.add(new testCommand());
registeredCommands.add(new testCommand2());
```

You could also use wildcards but given your question I assume that's something to bother with later (as you'll have to deal with ["producer extends consumer super"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)).

Execution of methods only available in subtypes also uses `instanceof`:

```
for(Command command : registeredCommands) {
  if( command instanceof CommandTypeA typeA) {
   typeA.execute();
  }
}
```

---

> Can I do the same thing I have in mind in other (better) ways?

There are very likely better ways but those depend on your requirements.

One could be to actually maintain several lists, e.g. a `List<CommandTypeA>` and a `List<CommandTypeB>`. Any command that implements both is added to both.

Another way might be to actually move the methods up, e.g. into the `Command` interface (introducing it in the first place already is a way to improve your code) and provide default methods:

```
interface Command {      
   default Type executable() {
     return null; //or return Type.EVERYONE, Type.NOBODY etc. - whatever makes sense
   }

   default String description() {
     //return any sensible default description 
     return "a command";
   }
}
```

Doing this you can call both methods even if you have only a `Command` reference.